# Updating SVG animations

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, dynamic, svg

My code shifts a shape to the left, and fades during 2 seconds and repeats everything 1 second later

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="636px" height="155px" version="1.1">
 <g id="canvas" transform="translate(0.5,0.5)">  
 </g>
</svg>

<script language="javascript">

 var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  
 var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
 function svgElement(name, attributes) {
  var element = document.createElementNS(svgNS, name); //to create a circle, for rectangle use rectangle
  for (key in attributes)
   element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
  return canvas.appendChild(element);
 }
 function render() {
  while (canvas.firstChild) canvas.removeChild(canvas.firstChild);
  svgElement('rect', {x:x, y:"20", width:"100",height:"100",style:"fill:blue"})
 }
 var x = 100
 render()
 var wait = 0
 function clock() {
  if (wait > 0) {
   wait -= 1
   if (wait == 0)
    x = 100
  } else {
   x -= 10
   if (x < 1) {
    svgElement('animate', {attributeType:"CSS", attributeName:"opacity", from:1, to:0, dur:"2s", fill:"freeze"})
    wait = 30
   } else
    render()
  }
  
 }
 
 setInterval(clock, 100)
</script>
```

The problem is that opacity fading is immediate on the second iteration. The square disappears immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an animation timeline that starts running when the first animation is added and then continues. So your first animation runs at time 0.

For subsequent animations the timeline has run past 0 so as they begin at time 0 (there's no begin specified) they happen immediately.

- One solution (shown below) is to reset the animation timeline.
- The other would be to calculate the correct begin value for the animation - you could get it by calling canvas.parentNode.getCurrentTime for instance.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="636px" height="155px" version="1.1">
 <g id="canvas" transform="translate(0.5,0.5)">  
 </g>
</svg>

<script language="javascript">

 var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  
 var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
 function svgElement(name, attributes) {
  var element = document.createElementNS(svgNS, name); //to create a circle, for rectangle use rectangle
  for (key in attributes)
   element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
  return canvas.appendChild(element);
 }
 function render() {
  while (canvas.firstChild) canvas.removeChild(canvas.firstChild);
  svgElement('rect', {x:x, y:"20", width:"100",height:"100",style:"fill:blue"})
 }
 var x = 100
    var begin = 0
 render()
 var wait = 0
 function clock() {
  if (wait > 0) {
   wait -= 1
   if (wait == 0)
    x = 100
  } else {
   x -= 10
   if (x < 1) {
    svgElement('animate', {attributeType:"CSS", attributeName:"opacity", from:1, to:0, dur:"2s", fill:"freeze", begin:begin})
    wait = 30
    canvas.parentNode.setCurrentTime(0);
   } else
    render()
  }
  
 }
 
 setInterval(clock, 100)
</script>
```